# Delete file from storage using RNFetchBlob

Tags: android, react-native, filesystems, rn-fetch-blob

I have the following code to unlink/delete a file from the downloads folder I created also through the application using the same path.

*Note I am using the RNFetchBlob package.*

```
---
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs
const base64 = RNFetchBlob.base64
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs

RNFetchBlob.fs
      .unlink(dirs.DownloadDir + '/passpoint.config.xml')
      .then(() => {
        alert("File deleted");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
      });
---
```

I keep getting the following error;

```
[Error: Failed to delete '/storage/emulated/0/Download/passpoint.config.xml']
```

I thought it may have been the path but this is the same path I used to create the file and I can see the file via the File Explorer on Android.

**Solution**

```
fs.unlink(dirs.DownloadDir + '/passpoint.config.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as a quick solution (edit `AndroidManifiest.xml`)

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Or use more advanced techniques:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Answer (score -1):

Just add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the AndroidManifiest.xml file

```
<application
android:name=".MainApplication"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```